# How to arrange faces of a quad sphere to simplify neighbour lookup?

Tags: graphics, procedural-generation

I'm working on a procedural planet generator that uses a quad sphere, or [quadrilateralized spherical cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateralized_spherical_cube), to represent its surface.

Most authors seem to number and arrange the faces arbitrarily, and so did I. For example, this is the arrangement that [Wikipedia shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping) for cube maps (apparently the Direct3D convention, although Wikipedia presents it as "the way" without mentioning the zillion alternatives):

[image: Arrangement of cube map faces]

But this leads to an issue when you want to know the neighbours of a given pixel, for example for normal mapping, or all sorts of simulations. Given a triple `(face, u, v)` that identifies a pixel (where `u` and `v` are integer indices, not texture coordinates), the task is to find the four triples that identify its four neighbours.

In the face interior, this is easy. But on the edges, you have to take 24 cases of wrapping into account: 6 cube faces × 4 edges per face. In pseudo-C:

```
Index neighbor(idx: Index, direction: Direction) -> Index {
  switch (direction) {
    case UP: if (idx.v < SIZE - 1) {
      return Index { face: idx.face, u: idx.u, v: idx.v + 1 };
    } else {
      switch (face) {
        case 0: return Index { face: 2, u: SIZE - 1, v: u };
        // And so on for the other five faces
      }
    }
    // And so on for the other three directions
  }
}
```

It's tedious and error-prone, and the branching makes it potentially slower than needed.

Then I found the 2007 SIGGRAPH sketch [Creating Spherical Worlds (sap_0251)](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eajw/s2007/0251-SphericalWorlds.pdf) by Compton et al., which mentions:

> Further, by choosing face mappings to be permutations of the corresponding axes, it is possible to formulate efficient algorithms for wrapping between faces, and projecting a 3D point into a chart.

This tantalizing sentence is all we get; there's no further explanation, and I can't find any follow-up articles by these authors either.

*How* can we choose the face mapping to allow for efficient wrapping?

Comment: Can you better explain what kind of wrapping you need? Do you have (x,y,z) and want to determine which cube-map texels should be sampled? Do you have a `(face, u, v)` and want to find the texel to the left/right/up/down of it in (u,v) space?

Comment: @YakovGalka The latter. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some quality time with pencil and paper, I figured out a reasonably elegant way to do this. We still need to distinguish between even and odd faces, but that can be done with a modulo operation (compiled down to a bitwise AND), so it doesn't need branching.

The arrangement is as follows:

[image: Arrangement of cube faces]

The mapping of global axes to local axes:

```
 u     v    normal
+X    +Y    +Z
-X    +Z    +Y
-Y    -Z    +X
+Y    +X    -Z
+Z    -X    -Y
-Z    -Y    -X
```

Each global axis is used once in each column, so this is indeed a permutation. Whether it's the same one that the Spore developers designed, remains an open question.

There are certain rules now, for example, moving UP from face `f`,

- if `f` is even (0, 2, 4), we always find face `(f + 1) % 6` (1, 3, 5),
- if `f` is odd (1, 3, 5), we always find face `(f + 5) % 6` (0, 2, 4).

So the neighbour lookup becomes much simpler:

```
Index neighbor(idx: Index, direction: Direction) -> Index {
  switch (direction) {
    case UP: if (idx.v < SIZE - 1) {
      return Index { face: idx.face, u: idx.u, v: idx.v + 1 };
    } else {
      return Index { face: (face + 1 + 4 * (face % 2)) % 6, u: SIZE - 1 - u, v: SIZE - 1 }
    }
    // And similar for the other three directions
  }
}
```

There might still be room for improvement, so better answers are quite welcome!

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Adding a separate answer because of the difference in approach.

(This answer assumes that the UV coordinates are per-face in the range `0..<SIZE`, with `SIZE` being constant for all faces.)

I can't think of a good way of efficiently computing the the neighbouring `(face, u, v)` across the boundaries for arbitrary cuboid mappings, but it should be relatively easy to just store a mapping of it for each face. For each face, store four mappings, one for each primary direction in UV space (i.e, +U, -U, +V, -V). Each of these mappings should contain a reference to the next face in that direction along with mapping coefficients for transform `(u0, v0) -> (u1, v1)`.

For the example mapping above, face 2 (the top one) would have the following mappings:

```
up:
    faceID: 5
    u: SIZE-u
    v: SIZE-1
down:
    faceID: 4
    u: u
    v: SIZE-1
left:
    faceID: 1
    u: SIZE-v
    v: SIZE-1
right: 
    faceID: 0
    u: v
    v: SIZE-1
```

When doing a neighbour lookup, check if the lookup falls outside the dimensions (0..<SIZE) and if it does, use the lookup structure defined above. So if you're looking up the next position along the U dimension on the boundary of face 2, just check the mapping for 'right': face 0, with a u value equal to the original v value, and a v value equal to SIZE-1.

You will need some method for precomputing this data when creating the geometry.

---

### OLD ANSWER

Assuming the following:

1. This is for doing texture lookups.
2. You have control over the way textures are generated.

Then I propose an alternate solution.

Instead of finding an efficient way of mapping the neighbour relationship across the discontinuity, simply make the texel value outside the UV map region the same as the value in its corresponding neighbour polygon.

[image: sketch showing pixel value relationship]

Comment: You mean adding a 1px border around each face, copying the values from the neighbouring edge? I started out with that approach, actually. It's faster at runtime, but you still need to cover 24 arbitrary cases, you need to keep the borders in sync, and you need to keep track of whether a coordinate refers to the "padded" or "unpadded" face. An additional source of complexity that I'd rather avoid.

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of anything? Is the texture updating? The method I suggested is what is typically done in rendering (both real-time and not).

Comment: It's not a texture and it's not rendering. It's a representation of a map on a sphere, on which simulations are being performed. Think of tectonic plates, atmospheric and ocean currents, and so on. As said, your method isn't bad, it's just error-prone in a different way – and while it may solve the problem, it doesn't answer the question. Apparently the Spore developers figured out a way to arrange faces to facilitate quick neighbour lookup, and the question is what that arrangement would be.

Comment: Hm, this is an interesting problem. Question: the integer indices, are they per face? I.e, each face has 0 <= u < N and 0 <= v < N.

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but a lookup table doesn't answer the question either. It's no different (conceptually) from the `switch` statement shown in the question.

Comment: In that case I'm not quite sure what you're after. It's not really possible to make a function that does the connectivity mapping for arbitrary cuboids without storing connectivity information somewhere. And I disagree that it's conceptually similar to the `switch` statement(s). The lookup table works for any arbitrary arrangement of faces, and would support any geometry as long as it's made up of only quadrilaterals.

Comment: I suppose it might be possible to create a connectivity mapping function that takes as its input the *type* of quadball mapping it's dealing with, but considering how many possible ways there are of constructing and mapping a quadball it seems like it'd be very inefficient. There are, what, half a billion possible shapes?

Comment: 122800, not counting rotational symmetries (5! permutations * 4^5 orientations, keeping face 0 fixed). According to the quote I cited, at least one of these allowes for a simple function. The question is, which one?

Comment: I can’t think of a way of doing this where specific arrangements in UV space makes it easier to compute connectivity. Why don’t you just have a map of it, where each face edge has a structure for how to move across it?